# Check if two numbers are powers of the same number in php

Tags: php, math, exponent

For example, since 25 and 2.2360679775 (or 5^0.5) are both powers of 5, I want the function to return 5.
The only way I've found is to brute force it and just try every number.

```
$one=25;
$two=125;

for($b=2;$b<=10;$b++)
{
    $x=pow($one,1/$b);

    for($c=2;$c<=10;$c++)
    {
        $y=pow($two,1/$c);

        if($y == $x)
        {       
            return $x;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Any value is equal to 5 in some power. For example, Pi = 5^0.71126. So it is worth to change problem formulation

Answer (score 0):

As Mbo points out in the comments, every number (z) is the power some number (x) to some other number (y).  So, it's not entirely clear what you mean when you say, 'if two numbers are numbers of the same power'.  Notwithstanding, you can easily (without using brute force) find y given x and z, using the `log()` function in php, like so:

```
 $z=125;
 $x=5;
 $y=log($z, $x);
 print $z . ' is ' . $x . ' to the power of ' . $y . '.';
```

This should produce:

```
 125 is 5 to the power of 3.
```